# What to consider when evaluating Windows MultiPoint Server 2011?

Tags: windows-7, grub2, multipoint-server-2011

I want to test [MultiPoint Server 2011](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/multipoint/buy.aspx). Currently, I have a parallel Win 7 / Ubuntu 10.04 installation with grub 2 as boot manager.

> Can these two be used parallely to MultiPoint again using grub and what's the most frictionless procedure to get this setup correctly?

---

**edit** What I mean with frictionless: MultiPoint Server will certainly just like Windows 7 overwrite the MBR and thus make Grub2 unavailable. I just want to know whether there is something I can do *before* installation so that afterwards it is easier to restore grub then including MultiPoint, and *how* to restore Grub.

Also, what will happen to the Windows 7 installation? Can I include both Win 7 and MultiPoint server into the Grub menu?

Comment: Related: [Does Microsoft MultiPoint Server 2011 support hardware 3D acceleration and dual-head?](http://superuser.com/q/257050/35237)

Comment: @studiohack would you mind clarifying _why_ this is not a real question? I'd simply like to know what I should do before installing MultiPoint server which will certainly overwrite the boot sector and thus disable grub, and whether I can still use win 7 in parallel.

Comment: your original question was vague, but you clarified, so I reopened...

Comment: @studiohack thanks, I should have thought of these details

Comment: related: [What preparations should I make before reinstalling windows? @unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9334/863)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just quote pjc50's [answer at unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9334/what-preparations-should-i-make-before-reinstalling-windows/9446#9446):

> Some people have been able to get NTLDR to chain to grub:
>   http://stringofthoughts.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/booting-linux-from-ntloader-windows-bootloader/
>
> Although in practice it's easier to use a live CD. I usually do something like:
>
> ```
> mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/somewhere # mount the linux partition
> chroot /mnt/somewhere bash
> mount /proc
> grub-install /dev/sda2
> ```

Comment: I'll test the installation soon and update the answer then