# Does Microsoft MultiPoint Server 2011 support hardware 3D acceleration and dual-head?

Tags: windows, hardware-acceleration, multipoint-server-2011, direct3d

I know the original purpose is different, but could MultiPoint be used for gaming as well?

---

**update** this seems to be rather neglected, but what about audio? Does MultiPoint Server support more then one sound channel e.g. via onBoard sound + HDMI?

Comment: Related: [What to consider when evaluating Windows MultiPoint Server 2011?](http://superuser.com/q/257049/35237)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell (I haven't actuall yused it personally yet) it uses Hyper-V VMs and RDP + RemoteFX, so you'll be limited to the capabilites/requirments of RemoteFX.

Apparently RemoteFX will handle upto 4 monitors @1280 x 1024 in a 'VM setting', if your dedecated GPU has >275MB.  Less monitors/more video RAM as you increase resolution.

Check out:

- [Windows MultiPoint Server 2011 Planning Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=501ba465-382f-41cb-bbea-b9bf580e2bb2)
- RemoteFX - [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemoteFX) and [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/virtualization/archive/2010/03/18/explaining-microsoft-remotefx.aspx)
- [Hardware Considerations for RemoteFX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817602%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. That also makes me wonder about the audio capabilities... Guess I'll just have to test it which I'll do when I know the answer to [What to consider when evaluating Windows MultiPoint Server 2011?](http://superuser.com/q/257049/35237)

Comment: hello @TobiasKienzler did you test the solution, what about audio and video capabilities?  I want to use this in our charity school so i need some help.