# Computer "Server"

Tags: performance, users

so at home we had the idea of instead of buying 3 different pc's we would somehow create a "server" for the computers where a cable would come to our screens and keyboard and mouses, so the actual pc was somewhere else in the house with all the others.

Does such a thing exist?

And is it possible to have such a thing for high performance workflow? 
  (Compiling, High-End Games, just as if it was a separate pc )

EDIT: The distance would be very small, such as 10 - 5 m

Comment: I could imagine that with your high-end gaming requirement you would be better off with a long HDMI/DVI/DP Cable and a wireless Keyboard/Mouse hooked up to three PCs at a separate location in the house (plus audio). For office applications it is done with more or less thin clients and so called "Terminal Servers". That approach can easily host 10+ user sessions but not for high-end gaming. Maybe specify the distance you are talking about, to allow for people to suggest alternatives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can two users simultaneously share one pc](http://superuser.com/questions/106842/can-two-users-simultaneously-share-one-pc), also maybe check out [Does Microsoft MultiPoint Server 2011 support hardware 3D acceleration and dual-head?](http://superuser.com/questions/257050/does-microsoft-multipoint-server-2011-support-hardware-3d-acceleration-and-dual) for some ideas regarding gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. It exists in the form of a virtual machine hosting images for other computers and streaming its data, but you would still need a thin-client (a computer with low specifications) to connect a keyboard, mouse and monitor to.

You have to realize that a virtual machine itself requires power to run, and the clients also require additional power. So you'll need a very strong computer if you also expect the performance for each user to be high. The idea of virtualisation, is that all users are not always doing maximum performance tasks at the same time.

Also, high-end games usually require a high-end graphics card and any kind of streaming will add lag to the gaming experience. So virtualisation would only work for an office environment which can include compiling or 3d rendering.

So in the end, it comes down to how many users will do high-end gaming. If its just one user, the virtualisation could be done on the high-end pc that the gamer is on, but its more likely, that it is cheaper to buy 3 separate pc's, each pc designed for its user.

So long answer short, its likely not going to work because I estimate that the conditions in which you're going to use it, aren't office conditions.

Comment: you write "a virtual machine hosting images for other computers"  Do you mean multiple virtual machines?  otherwise i guess it'd be many users sharing the one virtual machine which would be similar to sharing a one physical machine.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this actually. One server with multiple accounts to dial into (Remote desktop) or a pc hosting multiple virtual machines where the user has the ability to do evertything with that machine. First one is cheaper in resources, but also limited in what the user can do.

Answer (score 0):

The device you are looking for is called a KVM Extender

It lets you have a Monitor(the 'Video' in KVM), Keyboard and Mouse. And the Computer can be put at a distance with a cable. It's also good if your computer is noisy - you can shut it away.

You may also want a KVM Switch, that lets you have one Monitor, keyboard and mouse,  and multiple computers.

```
Comp ---    \
Comp   ---   \    KVM Switch ->  KVM Extender------> Monitor, Keyboard,Mouse 
Comp    ---  /
```

then you have both the ability to switch between your computers, but to do so seated at a distance from them.

FYI- There are other variations of KVM that are useful.  A Reverse KVM switch, lets you have multiple 'consoles' (keyboard and mice and video/monitor) and one computer.  So you could sit at location A or B or C, to access a computer at location C. 
And for your further info, another called synergy works as software, lets you have one Keyboard Mouse , multiple Computer, multiple monitors. I used it years ago.  And windows lets you have one KMC multiple V.

```
Comp ---    \
Comp   ---   \    KVM Switch ->  KVM Extender------> Reverse KVM Switch 
Comp    ---  /                                             |
                                                           |
                                                         / | \    
                                                       /      \
                                                  Keyb        keyb
                                                  Video       vid
                                                  Mouse       mouse
                                                  location1   location 2
```

or instead of 3 comps on the far left you could have 1 and remove the KVM switch

```
           comp      ->  KVM Extender------> Reverse KVM Switch 
                                                 |
                                                 |
                                               / | \    
                                              /      \
                                           Keyb        keyb
                                           Video       vid
                                           Mouse       mouse
                                           location1   location 2
```

or

```
         comp
          |
          |
         \/
       reverse KVM------KVM EXTENDER----------------REVERSE KVM----Location B
          \                                                   |---Location C
           \
            \
            Location-A(keyb,vid,mouse)
```

(each location having a keyb,vid,mouse.)

Comment: I think OP wants the reverse. One PC, three sets of KB/mouse.

Comment: @techie007 well, no doubt you know, but to clarify for his sake or for others. He can get whatever he wants with what i've mentioned. I don't think he mentioned about multiple locations but i've mentioned that in the paragraph about a 'reverse KVM switch'.  I've added some more diagrams.

Comment: @barlop your solution makes it so only one person at a time can use the computer from different locations (the reverse one), yet you don't state this. I'm fairly sure he wants 3 users to work at the same time, otherwise they would just buy one pc with one set of kb/mouse/screen.

Comment: @LPChip ah I see I suppose he wants shared simultaneous use for his gaming.. yes you're right. i've used the set up I described, which is better than one pc with one set of kb/mouse/screen because it's convenient depending on where I am in the house or moving a noisy machine away. But yep I guess he probably wants simultaneous shared use.